# What is the difference between Apex:messages and Apex:PageMessages in VisualForce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am having some confusion while using PageMessages and Messages in my VF Pages. I'm using an apex controller to pass a message to my vf page but the problem is that if I use PageMessages then it showing the default validation error messages on that page. And if use Apex:messages then the error messages don't show up at all...

Answer (score 1):

apex:PageMessages is a containing component where any messages that have been added to the page will appear.

apex:pageMessage is a component that adds a single message to the page.

apex:message allows you to associate a message with a component

I've not used apex:messages - I can't see how it particularly differs from apex:pagemessages

ApexPages.Message is the class that is used to model a message.  A message isn't associated with a page until it is added via the ApexPages class.

ApexPages is a class that allows you to access the current page (through ApexPages.CurrentPage()) and manage messages for the current page.

I'd start off adding an apex:pageMessages component to the top of your page and then add some messages in programmatically via the ApexPages methods - that should help clarify things.

You can refer folloing link : http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/apexpagemessage-and-apexpagemessages-salesforce/

Answer (score 1):

**apex:pageMessages**

> This component displays all messages that were generated for all
>   components on the current page, presented using the Salesforce
>   styling.

[image]

**apex:messages**

> All messages that were generated for all components on the current
>   page. If an `<apex:message>` or `<apex:messages>` component is not
>   included in a page, most warning and error messages are only shown in
>   the debug log.
>
> This component supports [HTML pass-through attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) using the
>   "html-" prefix. Pass-through attributes are attached to the generated
>    tag. (Each message is contained in a list item.)

[image]

Functionality is same for both these components. Way of display is different. `apex:pageMessages` uses salesforce default styling. For `apex:messages` we need to add custom style using `styleClass` and `style` attributes available. Here is detail on [apex:pagemessages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm) and [apex:message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messages.htm).

Answer (score 0):

`apex:pageMessages` is the component where you can add multiple messages and it shows all the errors with formatting i.e. It displays all the messages that were generated for all components on the current page with formatting.

`apex:pageMessage` is used to display single message i.e. it shows the specified message with formatting.

`apex:messages` is similar to `apex:pageMessages` i.e. it shows all of the errors but with no formatting i.e. All messages that were generated for all components on the current page will be displayed without formatting.

`apex:message` shows only the error for the specified field i.e. it is used to display message for a specific component.